# Condition for affine independence

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, affine-geometry

> Let $E$ be an affine space attached to a $K$-vector space $T$. For a
> family $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ of elements of $E$ and any $a\in E$, the set
> $$\left\{\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i(x_i-a)+a\ |\ \lambda\in
>  K^{(I)}\land\sum_{i\in I}\lambda_i=1\right\}$$ is the **affine linear
> variety generated by** $(x_i)_{i\in I}$.

> Let $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ be a nonempty family of elements of $E$ and $k\in
>  I$. This family is said to be **affinely independent** if and only if the
> family $(a_i-a_k)_{i\ne k}$ is linearly independent in $T$.

Now, suppose $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ be a nonempty family of elements of $E$. Suppose that, for every $k\in K$, $a_k$ doesn't not belong to the affine variety generated by $(a_i)_{i\ne k}$. I want to show that this implies that $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ is affinely independent.

**Attempt:**

Since $I\ne\emptyset$, let $k\in I$. According to the above, it is sufficient to show that the family $(a_i-a_k)_{i\ne k}$ is linearly independent in $T$. So, let $\lambda\in K^{(I-\{k\})}$ such that $\sum_{i\ne k}\lambda_i(a_i-a_k)=0$. Then $\sum_{i\ne k}\lambda_i(a_i-a_k)+a_k=a_k$. This implies that $\sum_{i\ne k}\lambda_i\ne 1$. But how can this help me show that $\lambda=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that $(a_i)_{i\in I}$ is not affinely independent, that is, for some (actually every) $k\in I$, the vectors $a_i-a_k$ are linearly dependent.

This implies that one of them is a linear combination of the other ones:
$$a_j-a_k=\sum_{i\ne j,k}\lambda_i(a_i-a_k)\\
a_j=\sum_{i\ne j,k}\lambda_ia_i+(1-\sum\lambda_i)a_k$$
Or, subtracting any $a\in E$,
$a_j-a=\sum_{i\ne j,k}\lambda_i (a_i-a)+(1-\sum\lambda_i)(a_k-a)$, which shows that $a_j$ is an affine combination of the other ones.